# Jquery is not working with php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am beginner in jQuery and ajax so I am facing many problems.I have a function that not works when I'm testing. please help me to understand

Thanks.

html page

[image]

php page

[image]

Comment: why don't you post your codes here? no screenshot please !

Comment: It would be easier for everybody if you posted the code as actual text instead of screenshots.

Comment: First thing is first. You should read the instructions on how to ask a question (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Secondly, have you look at your server/php logs to see if there is anything wrong there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

im not sure it didnt work after you try like comments above. you should check via inspect element or firebug

as alternative you can try this

```
$(function() {

 $('#name').keyup(function(){

   var tname = $(this).val();
   $.ajax({
     url : 'fetch.php',type:'post',dataType:'json',
     data : {name:tname},
     success:function(rest){

         $("#mydiv").html(rest.data);
     }
   });

  });

});
```

and in your fetch.php

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])){

   $name = $_POST['name'];
   echo json_encode(array('data'=>$name));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are binding the keyup function before the document is fully loaded. So this bind is happening before you have the element, hence no bind.
Wrap it inside the document ready function so it executes only when the structure of the document is fully available.

```
$(function(){
    // your stuff
});
```

Comment: that's a duplicated answer.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
$( "#mydiv" ).html('data');
```

with

```
$( "#mydiv" ).html(data);
```

eg:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
      $('#name').keyup(function(){
        var name = $('#name').val();
        $.post( "fetch.php",{name:name} ,function( data ) {
          $( "#mydiv" ).html(data);
        });
      });
    });
</script>
```